# jQuery Validate plugin with custom rule remote validation not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validate plugn for FuelUX wizard form validation. Now I need to validate a couple of fields with remote validation. As my form is in a wizard and validation needs to happen when I click on the Next button, I added a custom rule for validation as below :

```
    $.validator.addMethod("validateRule", function(value, element) {

        var validator       = this;


        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type:"POST",
            data: data,
        })
        .done(function(valid) {

            if (valid == "true") {
                return true;
            } else {
                var errors = {};
                errors[element.name] =  valid;
                validator.showErrors(errors);
                return false;
            }

        })},'’);
```

and my validation is called from :

```
    $('#create').validate({
        errorElement: 'div',
        errorClass: 'help-block',
        focusInvalid: true,
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true
            },
            title: {
                required: true,
                validateRule:true
            },
```

When clicking on the Next button I am checking the displayed form is valid through

```
    $('#fuelux-wizard').ace_wizard().on('change' , function(e, info){


        if (info.direction == 'next' && !$('#create').valid()) {
            return false;
        }
    }).on('finished', function(e) {
        $('#create').submit();
    }).on('stepclick', function(e){
        //return false;//prevent clicking on steps
    });
```

The problem here is that when I check $('#create').valid() it is always false irrespective of what I am getting from server. I think it is not waiting for the ajax call to complete and moving to the next line of the code. How this can be fixed ?

Comment: did you try to add `async:false` to your ajax request?

Comment: Actually I am trying to do it without async:false;

Comment: why are you not using the remote rule....

Comment: The remote rule has exactly same issue. I will not wait for the AJAX call to finish and will redirect to step 2 in the Wzard

Comment: Nobody has this issue  ?